# Trace Host of a SOAP Request

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap, trace

The software my company uses has a web service which signature is more or less like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public DataSet MakeQuery(string sql) {
}
```

NOTE 1: I don't have the code for this.

Recently, we noted the Sql Server gets a lot of processes without dying, so I want to trace the input of this webMethod.

Is any way I can do this?

I was thinking of a SoapExtension, but i don't have the source code for the web service. 
basically I want to know the name of the machine that sends the SOAP request.

NOTE 2: The SQL Server's processes report the server as the host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to see what gets transmitted over the wire.

Comment: Wireshark will definitely help you out, just insure that you're not using SSL.  Here's a writeup of using Wireshark to debug web services:

http://molecularvoices.molecular.com/2008/troubleshooting-web-services-with-wireshark/