# Tracing the SOAP envelope that is being sent by a .NET web service client possible?

Tags: c#, .net, soap, web-services

A C# client application we developed calls an external SOAP web service of a third party company.

Now I want to trace the exact SOAP request envelopes that are being generated by the VS.NET-generated SOAP proxy in our application and transfered to the external SOAP web service.

The method of using a network monitor like Wireshark (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802595/trace-host-of-a-soap-request)) or using Microsoft Network Monitor is no option since the externl SOAP web service only provides an SSL/HTTPS URL, so the payload of the HTTP packages are encrypted and not viewable.

**My question is:**

Is there a way of configuring the .NET-built-in web service client classes to output/trace/log their underlying HTTP requests and responses that are being generated/received? (or maybe some kind of event to subscribe to?)

Comment: tcpMon may do what you want. I've used it to trace jax-ws web services.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using a standard web service (not WFC), you can extend the SoapExtension class as described here:

[http://www.blog.encoresystems.net/articles/how-to-capture-soap-envelopes-when-consuming-a-web-service.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20120215173958/http://www.blog.encoresystems.net/articles/how-to-capture-soap-envelopes-when-consuming-a-web-service.aspx)

If you're using WFC, then you can implement IEndpointBehavior and IClientMessageBehavior as described here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/archive/2007/08/23/writing-a-wcf-message-inspector.aspx

I use both, depending on whether I'm using web or service references.

Comment: +1 for the SoapExtension, used that successfully too. OP didn't mention if it was web/windows client. If web, then I don't believe the SoapExtenstion code in the link is websafe.

Answer (score 3):

You can use fiddler, perhaps, as a proxy and thus monitor HTTP/HTTPS requests. This won't require you to write any code on your part.

[Fiddler Web Debugger](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

It is worth noting that there are caveats to debugging HTTPS requests with Fiddler. This page explains how it can be done.

[Fiddler Web Debugger - Debugging HTTPS traffic with Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Fiddler, or System.Net tracing.

http://blogs.msdn.com/dgorti/archive/2005/09/18/471003.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203855(BTS.10).aspx

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged. Please include the most relevant parts of the linked document here for future reference.